# Fill drop downlist using jquery ajax post and get selected value on c# page

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I fill dropdownlist with ajax post on document.ready function but i want its selected value on cs page but it return blank value to me. Please help..below is my code

```
var mddlrole = $('#<%=ddlrole.ClientID %>');
    document.ready(function() {


        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "ReportBasic.aspx/getroledata",
            data: '{}',
            contentType: "application/json;",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(response) {
                debugger;
                xmlDoc = $.parseXML(response.d.toString()),
                   $xml = $(xmlDoc)
                $xml.find('Table').each(function() {
                    var OptionValue = $(this).find('RoleID').text();
                    var OptionText = $(this).find('Name').text();
                    var option = new Option(OptionText, OptionValue);
                    $(option).html(OptionText);
                    $(mddlrole).append(option);
                });

            }

        });
    });
```

on.cs page

```
string filterQuery = dlddlrole.SelectedItem.Value;
```

error coming as "Object refrence not set to instance of an Object"

please help.

Comment: Can you clarify... does the drop-down get successfully populated on page load?  (that's how I read your question at first, but it's not really clear, therefore the first part of my answer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move this line:

```
var mddlrole = $('#<%=ddlrole.ClientID %>');
```

inside of the dom load function like so:

```
document.ready(function() {    
      var mddlrole = $('#<%=ddlrole.ClientID %>');

....
```

Having that variable assignment at its present location will assign null to the variable because the dom hasn't loaded the dropdown at that point.

To access the value submitted to your code behind, use `Request.Form[ddlrole.UniqueID]` - but note that the options which you add dynamically on the client-side will disappear each time you post back (because they're not in viewstate).

I suggest that you should probably be binding your list of items to your dropdown on the server-side: your current approach makes your life unnecessarily complicated (and creates additional, probably unnecessary, round-trips to your server).

Comment: PS - is the error occurring client-side or server-side?

Comment: thanks we have to pick the value from Request.Form["ddlrole"].tostring()

Answer (score 1):

We can Pick this value using Below Code

```
Request.Form["ddlrole"].ToString()
```